# php crontab -l showing different result from command line

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I created a file name 'testCrontab.php' in /var/www/html folder on amazon ec2, ubuntu-based,

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
var_dump($output);
```

The problem is when I invoked this file in browser it shows

> string(207) "0 0,6,12,18 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testExec.php 0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testCrawlback.php 0 4 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testInsertCard.php * * * * * NEW_CRON * * * * * NEW_CRON "

Which I guessed those `NEW_CRON` are from the other time I tested inserting a new cron from php,
but when I invoked this file from command line by issuing `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testCrontab.php` it shows

> string(169) "0 0,6,12,18 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testExec.php
>   0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testCrawlback.php
>   0 4 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testInsertCard.php"

Also, command `crontab -l` result in the latter output.

Please help enlighten me what happen here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result will be different because when you are executing script via browser the user will be `www-data` or `nobody`. It will show the crons of that user. If you execute the script from command line it will show the crons of that particular user.

**Edit**

Set cron for webuser

```
sudo crontab -u webuser -e
```

List crons of webuser

```
sudo crontab -u webuser -l
```

webuser  will be `nobody` or `www-data` or `apache`

You can find it by executing the following code from web browser.

```
 <?php $output = exec('whoami'); 
    echo $output;
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!
So if I logged in to EC2 with 'ec2-user' how can I specify this user when I executed it from the browser?

Comment: first you have to find out which is your websuer . Save this code in a file and execute it via browser. `<?php $output = exec('whoami');
echo $output;`

Comment: Thank you very much Harikrishnan, you really save my day.

Comment: The result is 'apache'.
So I guess there is a certain php method to change this?